# Issue with the connectionstring when executing with VSCode

Tags: sql-server-2014, graphql, asp.net-core-2.0, c#-5.0

I have VS2017, ASP.NET CORE, VS Code and SQL Server 2014 installed on my development environment.

I downloaded the sample code from the link: https://github.com/mmacneil/ASPNetCoreGraphQL and then opened it using VSCode.

I created a database with name `NHLStats` and updated the connectionstring to

```
"NHLStatsDb": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=NHLStats;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

Based on the instructions mentioned in the README.md document, I navigated to the root of the \NHLStats.Api folder and then executed the CLI dotnet run command.

On running the above command I see the below error:

> Application startup exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: connectionString
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder, String connectionString, Action`1 sqlServerOptionsAction)
>          at NHLStats.Api.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<ConfigureServices>b__0(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) in C:\Temp\ASPNetCoreGraphQL-master\src\backend\NHLStats.Api\Startup.cs:line 31
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.DbContextOptionsFactory[TContext](IServiceProvider applicationServiceProvider, Action`2 optionsAction)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitTransient(TransientCallSite transientCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>          at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
>          at NHLStats.Api.Startup.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__1(Type type) in C:\Users\sapatro\Learning\GraphQLDetails\ASPNetCoreGraphQL-master\src\backend\NHLStats.Api\Startup.cs:line 41
>          at GraphQL.FuncDependencyResolver.ResolveT
>          at NHLStats.Api.Models.NHLStatsSchema..ctor(IDependencyResolver resolver) in C:\Temp\ASPNetCoreGraphQL-master\src\backend\NHLStats.Api\Models\NHLStatsSchema.cs:line 11
>          at NHLStats.Api.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Temp\ASPNetCoreGraphQL-master\src\backend\NHLStats.Api\Startup.cs:line 41
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()